# Who was the intended audience for Dora and the Lost City of Gold?

Tags: production, dora-and-the-lost-city-of-gold

Dora and the Lost City of Gold (2019) was written to be significantly different in style from the original animated series. It contained more adult orientated humor and scenes of peril, and it made satirical references to the original throughout it;s runtime in a similar manner to the live action adaptation of Scooby Doo.

Which specific demographics were the writers and directors targeting when they released the film, and what was their reasoning behind this decision?

For example, were they aiming the film at teenagers who watched the original animated series as children, or a fresh audience?

Can this be verified through interviews, AMA, or official release content such as DVD comentary?

Answer (score 6):

### The core audience for this film is the parents of female children aged approximately 8-14, with their children.

The film's publicity people have this to say about their programme of activities;

> Strike worked with **mummy bloggers and parenting publications** to
> promote this fun action film, which follows Dora’s move away from her
> parents to start high school.
>
> [snip]
>
> We sent out a press release to push out a pre release free screening
> programme in selected Showcase Cinemas across the country. This deal
> was hugely successful and was promoted by 20 influential publications
> including **Primary Times, National Geographic Kids, Delia Online and
> The London Mother.** Strike also ran merchandise competitions on seven
> sites, including **Mumsnet, UKMums.tv, Five Little Doves and Boo Roo
> and Tigger Too.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Strike Media](https://www.strike-media.com/work/dora-and-the-lost-city-of-gold/)</sup></sub>

In the press tour, the cast and crew repeatedly mention that the film would be good for teens as well as 'young people' and 'young girls' and 'kids' and that Dora represents [a solid role model for teen girls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPm-1-XIMaI).

> **James Bobin:** *I do love the idea that she's just herself, and I think
> that's really important. It's hard to be yourself in a world where
> you're constantly being judged by other people or other ideas.
> Especially teenage kids. It's very important that you maintain a sense
> of self, and I hope that's what comes across the most.*
>
> <sub><sup>[James Bobin Interview: Dora and the Lost City of Gold](https://screenrant.com/dora-explorer-movie-james-bobin-interview/)</sup></sub>

and

> 

We can deduce that the goal was to aim the film the film at the parents of young teens and preteens, predominantly girls. Those parents would be aware of the brand but might not necessarily have seen the programme themselves.

The film's writer and director notes that parents and children enjoy films on different levels, so there was an intention of adding things that parents would enjoy that children might miss.

Comment: Off Topic but, she was "being herself"? I thought that they were saying that she was autistic?

Comment: @AaarghZombies - I don't think there's been any confirmation that she's autistic. She acts oddly because she's been raised oddly.